# jQuery on() method cross browser compatibility?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is attaching an event listener with jQuery's `on()` method cross browser compatible?

I think I remember that the ancestor `live()` didn't consistently work - correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: apparently `live()` method did not work in some cases in jQuery 1.3.2 http://blog.bigbinary.com/2009/10/14/how-live-method-works-in-jquery-why-it-does-not-work-in-some-cases-when-to-use-livequery.html I know that's a long time but there was something I remembered :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `.on` is cross browser compatible. `.live()` has been deprecated, as noted [here](http://api.jquery.com/live/). The page for `.on` is [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/). jQuery's own documentation on which browsers they actively support is found [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Browser_Compatibility).

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with `.live` or `.on` but your own code and how it uses them. One is not more cross-browser than the other.

Comment: Indeed, you can have have the most cross-browser library in the world but if you use `live` on `onbeforeunload` it will be just as uncross browser as the next code.